# WCF service different speeds for different devices

Tags: android, performance, wcf, iis

I have a WCF service (basicHttpBinding) that an app points to (via IIS6).

When an iPhone (4 or 5) uses it, it's fast.

When a Samsung Galaxy S2 uses it, it's fast.

When a Samsung Galaxy S3 uses it, it's very slow.

By "it" I mean hitting a single endpoint that carries out multiple operations before returning a result (using the same login credentials and other data).

If I look in the server logs, there is a substantial difference in the time it takes to perform these operations *within one server-side function*. So it's not like it takes longer to access the service, or to receive the result. Accessing it via that type of device makes the very *operations themselves* run slow.

Some reading I've done has suggested disabling HTTP compression. I didn't have it enabled, but when I enabled it it made the iPhone and S2 run as slow as the S3.

Is there an IIS setting I don't know about, or some difference in the way the S3 accesses services??

Comment: your sure the app was not running in debug mode?

Comment: It was (thanks!) but Release mode has made no difference.